# Error (0x0 0x0) [Golang /Window10/64bit]

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, go

I was testing Golang Html/Templates with the Go script below and ended up getting **Error (0x0 0x0)**  (the browser page never loads) .However,Javascript loads fine in the same browsers(Chrome,Edge).
How to resolve this issue?
(I do have an unactivated version on Windows10-64bit.)

**ENVIRONMENT**

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=D:\Script\Golang
set GOPROXY=
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build325815430=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

**SCRIPT**

```
package main

import (

    // "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    "time"
    // "golang.org/x/mobile/app"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", randNum)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))

}

func randNum(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    // Create random number

    aRand := rand.Intn(100)

    type RNumber struct {
        A int
    }

    Rnum := RNumber{aRand}

    //Show Template
    Tmp1, err := template.New("randNum1").Parse("HTML NUMBER ======> {{.A}}  ")
    if err != nil {
        print(err)
    }
    err = Tmp1.Execute(w, Rnum)
    print(err)//<==========Error (0x0 0x0)
    time.Sleep(3000 * time.Millisecond)

    //Loop
    randNum(w, r)

}
```

Comment: You are never returning from the http handler. Once you generate your output, you have to return so the connection can be flushed and terminated. You are not looping, you're in an enabled recursion that will never terminate and overflow the stack eventually. Also, what does print() do?

Comment: `print` is a builtin function like len, cap, make, println, etc. It's not as full featured as fmt's print functions. I had troubles redirecting output that `print` put on the screen. `(0x0 0x0)` is what it prints when `err` is `nil` (not sure why, it looks like it's trying to print two fields but if it's nil there shouldn't be any fields). And as @bserdar said, you're recursively calling the function at the bottom. You probably don't want to do that.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I never knew there's a print builtin. Looks like it is printing the internals of the value (error is an interface, and 0x0 0x0 is the type and value of the interface)

Comment: @bserdar Honestly `print` and `println` are more of a pain than an aid. They are NOT drop in replacements to fmt.Print and fmt.Println. They don't let you format anything, they don't print structs the same way, they seem to print directly to the terminal rather than going through stdout. I'd just avoid them.